# Selecting records from slowly changing table with a set of dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, t-sql, set-based

I have a slowly changing table,a new row is created each time any of the source fields are changed. Some metadata is added to show when that version was valid. This is a simplified example(dates are dd/mm/yyyy format) that doesn't show the fields which have changed.

| Startdate | Enddate | Currentrecord | unique id | serial_number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 15/12/2020 | 31/12/2020 | 0 | 1 | 2345 |
| 15/12/2020 | 8/3/2021 | 0 | 2 | 1234 |
| 19/9/2020 | 15/2/2021 | 0 | 3 | 2345 |
| 15/12/2020 | 8/3/2021 | 0 | 4 | 3456 |
| 9/3/2021 | 10/3/2021 | 0 | 5 | 3456 |
| 16/2/2021 | 10/3/2021 | 0 | 6 | 2345 |
| 9/3/2021 | 26/3/2021 | 0 | 7 | 1234 |
| 27/3/2021 | 2/5/2021 | 0 | 8 | 1234 |
| 11/3/2021 | 17/5/2021 | 0 | 9 | 3456 |
| 3/3/2021 | 27/4/2021 | 0 | 10 | 4567 |
| 20/1/2021 | 7/4/2021 | 0 | 11 | 5678 |
| 3/5/2021 | 30/6/2021 | 1 | 12 | 1234 |
| 25/5/2021 | 31/5/2021 | 0 | 13 | 2345 |
| 8/4/2021 | 22/5/2021 | 0 | 14 | 5678 |
| 1/6/2021 | 26/6/2021 | 0 | 15 | 2345 |
| 18/5/2021 | 3/6/2021 | 0 | 16 | 3456 |
| 27/6/2021 | 2/8/2021 | 0 | 17 | 2345 |
| 28/4/2021 | 28/6/2021 | 0 | 18 | 4567 |
| 23/5/2021 | 6/9/2021 | 0 | 19 | 5678 |
| 4/6/2021 | 28/6/2021 | 0 | 20 | 3456 |
| 29/6/2021 | 25/7/2021 | 0 | 21 | 3456 |
| 3/8/2021 | 31/12/9999 | 1 | 22 | 2345 |
| 26/7/2021 | 31/12/9999 | 1 | 23 | 3456 |
| 15/10/2021 | 31/12/9999 | 1 | 24 | 4567 |
| 7/9/2021 | 1/11/2021 | 0 | 25 | 5678 |
| 22/9/2021 | 10/11/2021 | 0 | 26 | 6789 |
| 2/11/2021 | 16/11/2021 | 0 | 27 | 5678 |
| 17/11/2021 | 21/11/2021 | 0 | 28 | 5678 |
| 15/7/2021 | 31/12/9999 | 1 | 29 | 7891 |
| 22/11/2021 | 31/12/9999 | 1 | 30 | 5678 |
| 26/11/2021 | 31/12/9999 | 1 | 31 | 6789 |
| 15/6/2021 | 31/12/9999 | 1 | 32 | 8912 |

There is only one record for each serial_number for any given point in time (i.e. the dates ranges will not overlap for identical serial_numbers) but there might be gaps between episodes for a some serial_numbers (representing something leaving and returning after a gap in service).

I want to supply an arbitrary list of datetimes, say midnight on  01/01/2021, 15/03/2021, 27/05/2021. 23/10/2021. I want to return a set of records, containing every record which was in effect on each of the dates, with each row labelled with the date it was selected by. So the above example should return this.

| date | unique id | serial_number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/2021 | 2 | 1234 |
| 1/1/2021 | 3 | 2345 |
| 1/1/2021 | 4 | 3456 |
| 15/3/2021 | 7 | 1234 |
| 15/3/2021 | 9 | 3456 |
| 15/3/2021 | 10 | 4567 |
| 15/3/2021 | 11 | 5678 |
| 27/5/2021 | 12 | 1234 |
| 27/5/2021 | 13 | 2345 |
| 27/5/2021 | 16 | 3456 |
| 27/5/2021 | 18 | 4567 |
| 27/5/2021 | 19 | 5678 |
| 23/10/2021 | 22 | 2345 |
| 23/10/2021 | 23 | 3456 |
| 23/10/2021 | 24 | 4567 |
| 23/10/2021 | 25 | 5678 |
| 23/10/2021 | 26 | 6789 |
| 23/10/2021 | 29 | 7891 |
| 23/10/2021 | 32 | 8912 |

I can see how to do this with a cursor, stepping through each date putting them into a variable and using something like

```
select @date, [unique id], serial_number
from example
where @date between start_date and end_date
```

to get the rows.

I can’t work out a pattern that would do it in a set based approach. My preferred SQL version is TSQL. Sorry as this is almost certainly a repeat, but I can't find a form of words that hits a worked example.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a temporary table to accomplish this.

```
CREATE TABLE #RequestedDates([Date] DATE)
```

You insert your dates you want into a temporary table.

```
INSERT INTO #RequestedDates([Date])
VALUES ('2021-01-01'), ('2021-03-15') /*Other dates*/
```

And then you join with the temporary table and use the between clause to get the valid results.

```
SELECT rd.[Date]
  , t.UniqueId
  , t.SerialNumber
FROM MyTable t
INNER JOIN #RequestedDates rd on rd.[Date] BETWEEN t.StartDate AND t.EndDate
ORDER BY rd.[Date]
  , t.UniqueId
  , t.SerialNumber
```

Answer (score 1):

You can join to `VALUES` with the dates you need.
Then join the datetimes on the range.

```
SELECT 
  datetimes.dt as [date] 
, t.[unique id] 
, t.serial_number
FROM example t
JOIN (VALUES
 (cast('2021-01-01 00:00:00' as datetime)), 
 ('2021-03-15 00:00:00'), 
 ('2021-05-27 00:00:00'), 
 ('2021-10-23 00:00:00')
) datetimes(dt) 
  ON datetimes.dt >= t.start_date
 AND datetimes.dt <= t.end_date
ORDER BY datetimes.dt, t.[unique id], t.serial_number
```